# drawing a diagram with text in php/python

Tags: php, draw

I'm looking for a way to create this :

http://goo.gl/PNj45

With php OR python using data fetched from user input. I know the `connection`s and the `text`s. It's not practically possible too use google chart API in this case.

Any insights?

Comment: Displaying flow charts in a way so that nothing is touching or overlapping is a difficult problem.  Do you know any constraints about your user input, such as how many connections maximum, or if there is always a trivial way to lay it out?  Otherwise, it's just a matter of using your language's graphical libraries to draw the icons, arrows, and text overlays.

Comment: thanks for reply, i know that I have a central box that has 1-5 connection to boxes in left, 1-5 connections to boxes in right.

Comment: readily, something like this (:D)              x <--0--> y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tool you may find useful is [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/)

Comment: that was the right choice. it's even unicode compatible ! ( i write programs in farsi )